# loopback upsert with allowExtendedOperators

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I'm trying to do an `upsert` where I `$push` a new element onto a field that is an array.

However, whenever I use `$push` I get the error telling me that I'm not allowed to use `$` at the beginning of operators.

Here's the debug trace:

```
loopback:connector:mongodb create +3s ThingUser { user: 'gerald', '$push': { things: 'hats' } }
  loopback:connector:mongodb MongoDB: model=ThingUser command=insert +2ms [ { user: 'gerald', '$push': { things: 'hats' }, _id: undefined },
  { safe: true },
  [Function] ]
  loopback:connector:mongodb Error:  +5ms { [MongoError: key $push must not start with '$']
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'key $push must not start with \'$\'' }
  loopback:connector:mongodb create.callback +0ms ThingUser { [MongoError: key $push must not start with '$']
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'key $push must not start with \'$\'' } null
```

It seems as though I'm not putting `allowExtendedOperators` in the correct place. I have tried *everywhere* where does this thing go? Can it not work with `upsert`?